# ORA-00936: 式がありません。

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
SELECT          syainNo
        ,name
        ,date
        ,place
        ,time
         FROM YOTEI_DATA_TBL;
```

をoracle dbに作成しましたものをselectしたのですが、

```
ORA-00936: 式がありません。
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
行16 列5
```

でエラーとでました。

確認したら、カラムは存在してるのですが、selectが実行できなくこまっております。
アドバイスお願いいたします。

Comment: 手元で確認できないのですが、カラム名に使用している `date` が Oracle で予約語であるためだと思います。 `"date"` とダブルクオートでくくってエスケープしてみるとどうでしょうか。

Comment: `time` も予約語ですね。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。解決することができました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

カラム名に使用している `date` と `time` が Oracle における予約語であるのが原因だと思います。

対策として、`"date"` のようにダブルクオートでくくってエスケープしてみてください。

---

*この投稿は [@出羽和之 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54040/ora-00936-%e5%bc%8f%e3%81%8c%e3%81%82%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93#comment56778_54040) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*